# Lokijs remove item by value

Tags: javascript, lokijs

I have this small db i have created in loki js

```
var db = new loki('loki.json');
var children = db.addCollection('children');
```

I have added some items and now i am trying to remove an item by the value.
I am storing my values like this

```
var date = new Date(); 
var timestamp = date.getTime(); 
children.insert({name:pn,ts:timestamp});
```

and removing like this

```
var results = children.find();
console.log('before removal',results);
children.chain().find({'name':field_val}).remove();
console.log('after removal',results);
```

This is the result screenshot

[image]

My removal code does not work since it does not remove all items and does not remove in the correct order.

How can i remove an item by value?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it should be `children.chain().find({'name':field_val}).remove();`

Comment: that gives results.chain is not a function